Non-local games: A game has a perfect local density if and only if it has a perfect deterministic strategy
This is about 'Two Players Cooperative Games':
Such a game is described by two input sets $I_A, I_B$, two output set $O_A, O_B$, and a function $V : I_A \times I_B \times O_A \times O_B \to \{0, 1\}$, often called the rules or verification function, where
$W := f(x, y, a, b) : V(x, y, a, b) = \{1\}$ is the set of correct or winning 4-tuples and 
$L := f(x, y, a, b) : V(x, y, a, b) = \{0\}$ is the set of incorrect or losing 4-tuples.
A deterministic strategy for such a game is a pair of functions $f: I_A \to O_A,\ g : I_B \to O_B$ such that whenever Alice and Bob receive input pair $(x, y)$ they respond with output pair $(f(x), g(y))$.
Einstein attempted to explain Entanglement away with a theory of local, hidden variables. Essentially this theory postulates that the randomness observed in quantum measurements is occurring because there is some hidden probability space $(\Omega, P)$ and for each $x\in I_A, y\in I_B$ random variables
$f_x : \Omega\to OA,\ g_y : \Omega \to O_B$ such that each time an experiment is conducted, one is really evaluating these random variables at some unknown point $\omega\in \Omega$, i.e., if Alice conducts measurement $x$ and Bob measurement $y$, then the values of the outcomes will be $a= f_x(\omega), b= g_y(\omega)$ and the only reason that we cannot predict a priori the values of the outcome is that we do not a priori know which point! We will be evaluating these random variables at when we perform the measurement.
In this case $p(a, b|x, y)= P( {\omega\in\Omega : f_x(\omega)= a, g_y(\omega)= b })$.
A perfect local strategy is given by $\forall (v, w), \ P({\omega \in \Omega : V(v, w, f_v(\omega), g_w(\omega)) = 0}) = 0$
$\textbf{problem :}$ Prove that a game has a perfect local density if and only if it has a perfect deterministic strategy.
$\textbf{answer :}$ For one implication, if we have a perfect local strategy then set
$$\Gamma = \bigcap_{v\in I_A,\ w\in I_B} \{\omega \in \Omega | V(v, w, f_v(t), g_w(t)) = 1\}$$
then $P(\Gamma) = 1$ when $I_A$ and $I_B$ are finite sets; ($\Gamma$ is non-empty). If we choose any $\omega \in \Gamma$ and set $h(v) = f_v(\omega)$ and $k(w)= g_w(\omega)$, and it is easily checked that this is a perfect deterministic strategy.
$\textbf{question: }$ Why do we need $I_A$ and $I_B$ to be finite to take the intersection? Do we need to use the axiom of choice in the case they are infinite?

Local densities are probabilistic combinations of deterministic strategies. Now suppose that there is perfect local density coming from a non-trivial mixture of perfect deterministic strategies and find a contradiction.

Your question is way too verbose. You wasted more than 10 paragraphs repeating what everyone knows, and didn't even define what is "perfect local density".

I edited and changed the question

There is still no definition of "perfect local density".
